# Does anybody know what companies are currently using agile iconix process?

Tags: agile, methodology, iconix

Does anybody know what large companies are currently using agile iconix process??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for list of things, and because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ones I know are the one I could find on the [ICONIX Software Engineering](http://www.iconixsw.com/) corporate website:

> Case studies: see how [ESRI Professional Services](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/downloads/pdf/esri_lbs_delivery_case_study.pdf), [Virginia Department of Motor Vehicles](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/downloads/pdf/dmv_csi_case_study.pdf), and [Large Synoptic Survey Telescope](http://iconixsw.com/Articles/LSST_case_study_20080825.pdf) are succeeding with ICONIX Process

I may be wrong but to me, the ICONIX methodology isn't really widely used and it
looks more like a way to sell their [Enterprise Architect](http://www.iconixsw.com/EA/ProductPage.html) product.

And personally, I never had big successes with too much UML centric approaches (à la MDA).

Comment: thanks for your reply. so how do you come up with a design?

Comment: @NBrowne I don't think specifying everything in a UML model is required to come up with a design.

Answer (score 1):

I like the process and used it well in several projects. I just want to give some of my thoughts on it:

1. Iconix is based on domain driven design. Domain comes first. This is fine, however we need to be aware of a boundary conditions. To put is simply, domain driven design works for the relatively complex projects. There may not be a domain model as design pattern at all since it may not be the best choice for every system.
2. Iconix assumes sophisticated deisgn.  Not every project needs it and not every project has developers capable of absorbing it. There are tons of data-centric or purely data manipulation applications out there.
3. No community, stale web site. I don't know of anybody who uses the process.